# Proper html page structure? What should be included in header/content?

Tags: html

newbie self learning web design. In theory, I've learned html and css. In practice I've hit a snag. Here is the barebones code so far.

```
<header>
        <a id="site-logo" href="/"><img src="#" alt="Dot Design" /></a>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>About</li>
                <li>Services</li>
                <li>Portfolio</li>
                <li>Contact</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <form id="search">
            <input type="search" placeholder="Search" />
        </form>
</header>
<div id="content>
   <!-- content goes here -->
</div>
```

Here is the template I'm referencing for practice: http://min.us/i/braxZb11KQjfD
The problem is I'm not quite sure if:

- everything in the red box should go in the header
- only the jquery slider should go in the header
- everything in the red box should not be in the header
- or it doesn't matter and just a matter of preference

Since I have no experience, I'd like some feedback as to which method is correct? Or more generally accepted and preferred?

Thank you very much for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything in the red box should not be in the header unless that content describes the page content. Which at this point it does't look like it does. It's just homepage content. Unless the intro is directly related to the slider there's no reason to combine the two.

```
<header></header>
<div id="content">
    <figure class="hero"></figure>
    <p class="lead"></p>
    ...
</div>
```

Would work fine as a setup. The HTML offers a way to group elements semantically (for instance the section and header) or to provide hooks for styling (#content and .hero etc).